# Calling Constructor with in constructor in same class

Tags: c++, constructor, garbage

I was expecting the output 2, 3 but I'm getting garbage value. Why's that?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int a, b;

    A()
    {
        cout << a << " " << b;
    }

    A(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        A(); // calling the default constructor
    }
};

int main()
{
    A ob(2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside this constructor:

```
A(int x, int y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;
    A(); // calling the default constructor
}
```

call `A();` creates a new temporary object that is immediately deleted after this statement. Because the default constructor `A()` does not initializes data members `a` and `b` then it outputs a garbage.

This temporary object has nothing common with the object created by constructor `A( int, int )`.

You could rewrite your class the following way:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;

    A(): A(0, 0) {}

    A(int x, int y) : a(x), b(y)
    {
        cout << a << " " << b;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why is it possible to create a temporary anonymous object?

Comment: @zenith  Why not? Maybe it has some side effects.

Comment: @zenith: "temporary anonymous" doesn't make sense. If an object has a name, it's not a temporary.

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant "temporary" in the sense that it gets immediately deleted.

Comment: @zenith: Indeed, an object with a name doesn't get deleted immediately, only at the point where its name goes out of scope.

Comment: Same thing happening here too ... ?                           #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
 public :
 int a,b;
 A(){
  a=2,b=3;
 A(2,3);
 cout<<" after call";
 }
 A(int ,int ){
  cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 }
};
int main(){
 A ob;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @Rajesh Sethi  The code you have showed in your preceeding comment does not correspond the code I have showed in my post. Here again this constructor A(int ,int ){ cout<<a<<" "<<b; } }; does not initialize data members a and b. And the deafult constructor creates temporary object A( 2, 3 ) that has nothing common with the object the default constructor creates.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow  My doubt is whether the parameterized constructor in the default constructor also creating an temporary object..plz see the following code ........                      #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
 public :
 int d,c,a,b;
  int e,f,g;
 A(){
 A(2,3);
 cout<<" after call";
 cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 }
 A(int x,int y ){
  a=x, b=y;
  cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 }
};
int main(){
 A ob;
 return 0;
}   //o/p: 2 3 after call garbage garbage

Comment: @Rajesh Sethi The default constructor in your example does not initialize data members.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow ,okk All i could understand is that when the parameterized constructor is being called in the default constructor a temporary object is created and destroyed then and there ..      #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
 public :
 int a,b;
 A(){
 a = 4, b=5; 
 A(2,3);
 cout<<" after call ";
 cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 }
 A(int x,int y ){
  a=x, b=y;
  cout<<a<<" "<<b;
 }
};
int main(){
 A ob;
 return 0;
}// o/p : 2 3  after call 4 5

Comment: @Rajesh Sethi Call A( 2, 3 ) inside the body of the default constructor simply creates a temporary object with its own data members a and b. This call does not change data members a and b of the object created by the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here you output a and b which are not initialized:

```
A(){
cout<<a<<" "<<b;
}
```

And here you initialize a and b, but you create an anonlymous temporary object

```
A(int x , int y){
    a = x; b= y;
    A(); // !!!! CREATES AT TEMPORARY ANONYMOUS OBJECT WITH IT'S OWN a and B
}
```

To use a delegated constructor (i.e. using another constructor to finish the construction process of the SAME object) you have to use the delegeted constructor in the initialisation list :

```
A(int x , int y) : A() { a=x; b=y;  }
```

**Unfortunately**, when you use delegation, the delegate must be the ONLY meminitializer in the list.  This requires that the initialisation of a and b would happen after A().

Another alternative:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;
    A() :  A(0, 0) { }  // use a delegated ctor 
    A(int x, int y) : a(x), b(y) { cout << a << " " << b; }
};
```

Still another alternative, using defaults (without reusing a constructor) :

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;
    A(int x=0, int y=0) : a(x), b(y) { cout << a << " " << b; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call the default constructor, what you did is create a temporary **A** object, which happen to have its members uninitialized before you printed the output. Perhaps what you wanted to do is constructor delegation, which would look like

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int a, b;
public:
    A(): A( 0, 0 ) {
        std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
    }
    A( int x, int y ): a( x ), b( y ) {}
}

int main()
{
    A object_a {}; //prints 0, 0
    return 0;
}
```